# How to change a certain text or term of WordPress into a custom into the whole site?

Tags: functions, filters

In my WordPess site for client, I used Posts as Products, Comments as Customer Review, Subscribers as Registered Customers and so on. For client's I used [Admin Menu Editor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor%E2%80%8E) to edit the `wp-admin` menu item's titles, i.e.:

- Posts > Products,
- Add New > Add New Product;
- Pages > Web Pages etc.

But scenario is:
 When someone clicks on the menu "Products", the page appears with "Posts". That's a bit fishy! :(

If it is possible I want to make a change in the visualization into the whole site that makes the *word* "Post" into "Product", "Page" into "Web Page" etc. and relative plurals (i.e. "Posts" into "Products" etc.). - perhaps a kind of filtering...

**Awareness:** But I want no conflict with the WordPress keyword "Post" (the post type), or the WordPress keyword "Contributor" (the user role) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a trick. You can use the WP translation functionalities.

There are 2 possibilities:

1. You are using the default English version of WP
2. You are using a localized version.

---

#### Case 1:

1. Under content folder (usually `/wp_content`) create a folder named 'languages'

---

#### Case 2:

1. Under content folder (usually `/wp_content`) there is a folder named 'languages' in which there are some files
2. Two files (at least) are related to your language, they are named like `xx_XX.po` and `xx_XX.mo` where xx_XX is the code for the language. Sometimes there are another 2 files: `admin-xx_XX.po` and `admin-xx_XX.mo`
3. If there are files `admin-xx_XX.po` and `admin-xx_XX.mo` make a copy these 2 files, otherwise make a copy of `xx_XX.mo` and `xx_XX.po`, and put it in a different folder.

---

Now you can follow the following instructions, not mind if yours is case 1 or 2:

1. Download, Install and Activate the plugin [Codestyling Localization](http://wordpress.org/plugins/codestyling-localization/)
2. In WP dashboard, under `Tools` menu you will find the menu item `Localization`, click it
3. Screen is parted in two, an the left you can see all your themes, your plugins and, first of all WordPress itself. On the right you can see al the languages available for WordPress, themes and plugin. In the WordPress row, if you are using a localized version you will see your language otherwise you will see nothing. Don't mind, click on the button **Add Language** and in the window that appear, choose a language that, for you, is as *strange* as possible, something like 'isiZulu' with language code 'zu_ZU' (it's the last one).
4. Now you can see language you have chosen in the list: there is a flag, language names and some buttons.
5. If you are running a standard English version of WP **skip** this step. Otherwise, open the folder `/wp_content/languages` and you will see 1 file, e.g. `zu_ZU.po`. Take the 2 files you have copied in the instructions of Case 2, rename the file `.po` in `zu_ZU.po` and the file `.mo` in `zu_ZU.mo` then copy these renamed files in `/wp_content/languages` (so replace `zu_ZU.po`).
6. Back to `WP Dashboard -> Tools -> Localization` and refresh the page. Click on the 'Rescan' button that is next to the new language flag. The plugin start its work and when finished click on the 'Edit' Button.
7. Now you will see a table with 2 columns, on the left there are the English strings of WordPress (every string used by WordPress is here, there are about 1600 strings!) on the *right* there are the translations (all blank if you are running a standard English version).
8. Start *translating*. Search for the words and sentences you want to change, e.g. "Posts" and translate them in your *personal language" e.g. "Posts" became "Products", and so on.
9. When finished, click on the button "**Generate mo-file**" in the header of the page.
10. Now you have to tell Wordpress to use your language. On your `wp-config.php` file write: `define('WPLANG', 'zu_ZU')`. Note: if you are using a localized version, this definition is **already** there: don't add again, change the language code instead.
11. Refresh the page in WP dashboard and see the magic :)

Comment: I previously did some .po edit with PO Edit software. But using 'Codestyling Localization' is a fun. Thanks for the nice solution. As you said: *and see the magic :)* - yap, it works like a magic. For next person who would try: It slowed my PC temporarily, when saving translated data temporarily; but it's temporary, I'm just mentioning it to assure you that, it's nothing. And the steps G. M. mentioned here are correct with very details. Thanks G. M. for a nice tricky answer. :)

Comment: You are welcome. Glad it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you really want [Custom Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/custom_post_types) that you can use to customize the names and capabilities of posts (and pages) to match your site's internals. You can use a plugin to generate them, but I prefer to control them within my theme's `functions.php` file and create them using the [GenerateWP](http://generatewp.com/post-type/) tool.

Once you have them working, if you still want to remove the Post and Page menus, take a look at the [`remove_menu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page) function and use it to hide/remove those pages. [Here's a writeup from Six Revisions](http://sixrevisions.com/wordpress/how-to-customize-the-wordpress-admin-area/) about how it works (a little dated, but it provides a good overview).
**Disclaimer**: I've never hidden the core Post/Page menus, so I don't know how it affects editing within a CPT.